# Visual Studio How to add Python module to Intellisense

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense

How do I add a custom python module to the Visual Studio IntelliSense code completion tool?

Situation: I am working on a python module that references another module that I have saved in /myPython/foo.py.

If I start to type foo.someDef I would like IntelliSense to recognize I am accessing that module and suggest a code completion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Visual Studio's Intellisense will recognize custom Python modules after they have been properly placed in the "site-packages" folder under the "Lib" folder in Python's directory.

For example:
/Python27/Lib/site-packages/myPython

Inside of the folder "myPython", put a plain text file called "__init__.py". Otherwise Intellisense will not recognize your package.

You may also have to click the "Refresh DB" under the Python Environments tab.

[image: Menu to Python Tools][image: Python Environments]

Comment: Where is "Refresh DB" in VS2013? That seems to be important because I checked all site-packages folders and they contained "\_\_init\__.py" files.

Comment: To access the "Refresh DB" button, switch the dropdown selection from "Overview" or "pip" to "IntelliSense".

Comment: Anyone else new to the Python Party might find this useful: http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html You can also find a bit about it in Mark Lutz's Learning Python.

Comment: The database refresh python environment stucks in VS 2017. There will be a correction in 15.7 as Steve Dower announced                              https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/222340/python-intellisense-database-refresh-frozen.html                                                                                                                                                                           Steve Dower [MSFT] · 26 03 2018 um 16:41 0  
But that does not work either

Comment: As Thomas Kadlec reported it does not work for 15.8. I have 15.9 and it stucks. Microsoft  set it to solved.

Comment: In case where you can't or don't want to move your modules, you can add the path to the module to the Search Paths in the Solution Explorer. This also allows you to step into the module's code correctly.