# Python IntelliSense/Code Completion in VS 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, python-3.5, ptvs

It appears that there are IntelliSense issues working with Python in Visual Studio 2015? I can't find a definitive answer or fix but may just be doing something wrong...

I have seen posts about adding IntelliSense for a module outside of your current project, but I don't even have any intellisense within my python project... Is this normal?

For instance, I have a handful of classes and properties, and other .py files (I guess these would be referred to as modules?) and methods, and anytime I try to reference any of these, I get ""... The application runs fine, things are referenced correctly using the import statements, but it just doesn't work. I've tried Refreshing the DB but still is not working...

If this is a bug or a known issue please let me know so I can stop wasting time on this otherwise if anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know. Let me know if any additional info is needed.

Thanks!
Tony

Comment: Hi Anthony, does your issue is solved or not?

Answer (score 1):

For the Python IntelliSense, this document shared us the features we could use in default:

https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Editor-Features

If it is the custom python module, you need to place it to the specific folder:

[Visual Studio How to add Python module to Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605416/visual-studio-how-to-add-python-module-to-intellisense)

If you want to add the Suggestion Mode in Python project, other community member has submitted a feature request to the VS product team:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/16800313-please-add-the-intellisense-suggestion-mode-to