# Visual Studio 2017: How to add Python module to Intellisense?

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

The same question has been answered here before for VS 2015:
[Visual Studio How to add Python module to Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605416/visual-studio-how-to-add-python-module-to-intellisense)

I'd like to know what is the situation in VS 2017? Is there any way to somehow link "myPthon" folder to the intellisense?

I think it is very general that people do not want to put their entire solution into the ".../PythonEnv/Lib/site-packages/myPython" folder. Actually my solution contains both C# and Python projects, obviously I dont want to move my C# projects into the python site-package folder. Is there any other way to make intellisense work?

It is very frustrating to see that these things still do not work automatically (if at all) in 2017 and I realz dont get the reason for that... ??? :S