# How to import custom python modules in Visual Studio Code to get code completion?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have compiled some python libraries (C++ bindings to python). I am using them with setting the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`
My question  is, how can I make them available to visual studio code? so that I can get code completion and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio How to add Python module to Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605416/visual-studio-how-to-add-python-module-to-intellisense)

Answer (score 2):

There is a section in the [documentation of vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing), where you can find a section to set up `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` in your `settings.json`.

Please read the [troubleshooting section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_troubleshooting) in the documentation to get IntelliSense for a custom module.

Be aware of the different settings between the operating systems. 
And point the `extraPaths` to your custom module.

Comment: I did it, but no luck. I guess in order to load the libraries correctly `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be adjusted too. My python libs has dependency to some other libs, which I placed in the same directory. Do you know what I can do here?

Comment: @Acki your question is very broad, please provide some steps you have tried to achieve the code completion. I would suggest, that all custom library-paths are in your settings.json file but I need more information to help you! And please consider reading the documentation I linked in the answer.