# Python in Visual Studio 2022 : package installed but missing

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I tried to use Python in Visual Studio 2022. I have ccreated an environment, imported packages using Pip but intellisense keeps saying they're missing.
What did i miss?
[image]

Comment: As a matter of fact, the fact that the package is underlined doesn't necessary mean that it's missing. I tried to run the script and it works. 
Maybe some kind of intellisense bugs or misconfigurations. :/

Comment: If you hover your mouse pointer over the line with the green underlines, what does it say? Or, what do your warnings say in your errors lists?  Or... is it sayings it is missing despite the fact that the code seems to work? If so, then yes, you may be right that intellisense is a bit off.

Comment: It says "ReportMissingImports: Import "mysql-connector" could not be resolved. 
In Visual Studio Options Panel, in the Text Editor section, i  have noticed that there is no intellisense section for Python, it's only for C#, F#, VB, C/C++.

Comment: Maybe here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605416/visual-studio-how-to-add-python-module-to-intellisense